# With the "git flow" approach, why are release branches merged into develop?

Tags: git, gitflow

In the [git flow workflow](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow), it is recommended to create branches for releases, and when the release-specific work is done, merge the result into the master and development branch.

I understand why we would merge a release branch into the master branch, rather than rebase master on the tip of the release branch: We don't want people to have history conflicts with master.

But I don't understand why it's recommended to merge the release branch into develop, rather than rebase develop off of master, at the commit merging the release branch into master. That seems more "natural" to me, and simpler to do.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What am I missing?

It breaks the [golden rule of rebasing](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/merging-vs-rebasing#the-golden-rule-of-rebasing): Never rebase a public branch.

Comment: But it's the "development" branch... it's not a problem if its history changes. There's no commitment to its usability or stability. Although, ok, my beef is with their philosophy, not with your answer.

Comment: @einpoklum It's not *the* develop branch. it's *a* develop branch, even if it's `origin/develop`. Unless you are the sole developer, at which point it doesn't really matter if you use a "standard" approach or not.

Comment: According to the flow article I linked to, there is _a_ (single) develop branch; and many feature branches.

Comment: @einpoklum *per* copy of the repository. `alice/develop` and `bob/develop` and `origin/develop` might be in different states

Comment: I don't think so... " this workflow uses two branches to record the history of the project. The master branch stores the official release history, and the develop branch serves as an integration branch for features. " - a branch-per-copy is not recording project history. Of course, history-recording and rebasing are compatible only under a certain view of history.

Comment: Going back to [the source](https://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/#decentralized-but-centralized), we see multiple repos in varying states

Comment: ... but a central repository with a single central develop branch, at that same link.

Comment: @einpoklum: Well, that's what's makes it public.

Comment: @einpoklum I'm working for you. I clone the repository and check out the "develop" branch. I make some changes. You rebase the "develop" branch. I push my changes. This creates a mess because you rebased the "develop" branch.

Comment: @user253751: You clone the repo. You start a feature branch off of your copy of the `develop`. The central `develop` gets rebased. You `pull -f` the central `develop`. Now, you must rebase your feature branch on the new `develop` before  landing your feature branch. Not seeing any problem here...

Comment: @einpoklum if there were any merge conficts, everyone has to repeat the fixes, and then resolve the "conflict" merging back

Comment: @einpoklum Yes, if you rebase then it is possible for everyone else to recover from it. It creates a mess which can be fixed. It doesn't make your repository explode in a giant fireball. Nonetheless, people generally prefer not to need to rebase their own branches because someone decided to rebase a branch on the server.

Comment: @user253751: It is not that different from when someone makes more commits at the head of `develop`, and you have to rebase off those commits.

Comment: @Caleth: Merge conflicts between what and what? I'm not following. Why does everyone have to repeat fixes?

Comment: @einpoklum you never *have to* rebase. You can `git merge develop feature`. Merge conflicts between `origin/release` and `origin/develop`, that you had to resolve when rebasing `origin/develop` on `origin/master`

Comment: @einpoklum It might be that if you *only* rebase, it's not so bad. But *mixing* rebases and merges on public branches gets you into a big mess, where work gets repeated